# "Complex" query with multiple conditions (BEGINNER)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm basically new to (postgre)SQL and have to write ONE query for following scenario. I bet it's almost laughable to the more experienced members here but please bear with me (I dont even have a database to test it right now).

**one query to show for each user (type=a):**
the last positive(successfull)"request" (request_id, creation_date, amount),
sum of "amount" of all failed "requests", 
ratio of positive-to-negative requests.

**given two tables:**
 **user_account** – contains the unique accounts of users columns:   account_id (type:int8, key column, IS_NULLABLE:NO),  creation_date (type:timestamp),   account_type (type: varchar, possible values: {a, b})
**request** – contains each request:   request_id (int8, key column, IS_NULLABLE:NO) creation_date (timestamp),   account_id (int8),  amount (float8),  type (type:varchar, possible values {positiv, negativ})

So what I understood is I can bring the two tables together with the join statement like:

```
SELECT request.request_id,
request.creation_date, request.amount 
From user_account
INNER JOIN request ON (user_account.account_id = request.account_id)
Where request.type = POSITIV AND account_type = a;
SELECT sum(request.amount) as failed_amount
From user_account
INNER JOIN request ON (user_account.account_id = request.account_id)
Where request.type = NEGATIV AND account_type = a;
```

1. Provided that this is correct, how do I join them into one query? ( I read about subqueries and to put the second select statement in the WHERE clause?)
2. For the Ratio I guess, I have to count() the positive and the negative requests and divide them, but honestly I have no idea how to implement it in this case.

If someone could give me a short walkthrough, I would be super delighted and thankful.

Comment: probably not going to solve it all, just note that the join you did means you get ALL requests (with added columns and data about the corresponding user), not only the last requests. I would solve it by first finding a date of the last request for each user - `SELECT account_id,MAX(timestamp) FROM request  GROUP BY account_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr** the code block at the end should give you want you want, with some minor changes to make it work in postgre

Using subqueries is a more intermediate topic, so don't feel discouraged if you're not getting it. I'll walk you through it in a couple steps.

(1) Make up some test data and join tables

(2) Select Most Recent Positiv Request

(3) Select Sum of Negativ amount

(4) Select ratio of positiv to negativ counts

**Test Data and Reference**

For this answer, I'm going to be using the following tables as test data:

```
#user_account
+ ---------- + ------------- + ------------ +
| account_id | creation_date | account_type | 
+ ---------- + ------------- + ------------ +
| 1          | 2016-02-14    | B            |
| 2          | 2016-02-14    | A            |
| 3          | 2016-04-06    | B            |
| 4          | 2016-04-29    | B            |
| 5          | 2016-09-03    | A            |
+ ---------- + ------------- + ------------ +

#request
+ ---------- + ------------- + ---------- + ------- + ------------ +
| request_id | creation_date | account_id | amount  | request_type | 
+ ---------- + ------------- + ---------- + ------- + ------------ +
| 1          | 2016-03-08    | 1          | 4308.02 | positiv      |
| 2          | 2016-04-08    | 1          | 1718.56 | negativ      |
| 3          | 2016-03-11    | 2          | 911.50  | positiv      |
| 4          | 2016-03-12    | 2          | 38.42   | negativ      |
| 5          | 2016-03-12    | 2          | 110.12  | positiv      |
| 6          | 2016-05-08    | 3          | 1843.19 | positiv      |
| 7          | 2016-09-12    | 4          | 7234.11 | negativ      |
| 8          | 2016-10-12    | 4          | 515.51  | negativ      |
| 9          | 2016-10-12    | 5          | 0.01    | positiv      |
| 10         | 2016-10-18    | 5          | 13.02   | positiv      |
+ ---------- + ------------- + ---------- + ------- + ------------ +
```

I'm going to be using [table aliasing](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455(v=sql.105).aspx), and I've renamed your type field in request table to request_type. Oh, and one more thing: this is written in SQL Server, but it should work for postgre with only minor modifications :)

Starting simple, let's join the tables together and filter on account_type

```
select *
    from #user_account u
    inner join #request r on r.account_id = u.account_id
    where u.account_type = 'A'
```

which gives the following table which I'll use as a reference

```
+ ---------- + ------------- + ------------ + ---------- + ------------- + ------ + ------------ +
| account_id | creation_date | account_type | request_id | creation_date | amount | request_type |
+ ---------- + ------------- + ------------ + ---------- + ------------- + ------ + ------------ +
| 2          | 2016-02-14    | A            | 3          | 2016-03-11    | 911.5  | positiv      |
| 2          | 2016-02-14    | A            | 4          | 2016-03-12    | 38.42  | negativ      |
| 2          | 2016-02-14    | A            | 5          | 2016-03-12    | 110.12 | positiv      |
| 5          | 2016-09-03    | A            | 9          | 2016-10-12    | 0.01   | positiv      |
| 5          | 2016-09-03    | A            | 10         | 2016-10-18    | 13.02  | positiv      |
+ ---------- + ------------- + ------------ + ---------- + ------------- + ------ + ------------ +
```

**Select Request**

To understand a correlated subquery, let's imagine that I have the above table table and a variable `@account_id = 2`. By looking at the reference table, we can see that for account 2, we want to select reference_id 5 since it is the most recent positiv request. The following query gives us just that

```
select top 1 request_id
    from #request
    where account_id = @account_id
        and request_type = 'positiv'
        order by creation_date desc
```

To use this idea in our query, we need to turn it into a correlated sub query by replacing `@account_id` with `u.account_id`, like so

```
select    u.account_id
        , r.request_id
        , r.creation_date
        , r.amount
    from #user_account u
    inner join #request r on r.account_id = u.account_id
    where u.account_type = 'A'
        and r.request_id = (
            select top 1 request_id
                from #request
                where account_id = u.account_id -- correlate to the reference table
                    and request_type = 'positiv'
                order by creation_date desc
        )
```

which gives us exactly what we want

```
+ ---------- + ---------- + ------------- + ------ +
| account_id | request_id | creation_date | amount |
+ ---------- + ---------- + ------------- + ------ +
| 2          | 5          | 2016-03-12    | 110.12 |
| 5          | 10         | 2016-10-18    | 13.02  |
+ ---------- + ---------- + ------------- + ------ +
```

**Selecting Sum of Negativ Amount**

We'll use the same idea of correlated subqueries for the next two parts, but here we'll put them in the select portion of our statement since we no longer need to filter out any results. This query

```
select    u.account_id
        , r.request_id
        , r.creation_date
        , r.amount
        , ( select isnull(SUM(amount),0) -- replaces a null value with 0
                from #request
                    where account_id = u.account_id
                    and request_type = 'negativ' ) as SumOfFailed
    from ... -- same as above
```

gives us

```
+ ---------- + ---------- + ------------- + ------ + ----------- +
| account_id | request_id | creation_date | amount | SumOfFailed |
+ ---------- + ---------- + ------------- + ------ + ----------- +
| 2          | 5          | 2016-03-12    | 110.12 | 38.42       |
| 5          | 10         | 2016-10-18    | 13.02  | 0           |
+ ---------- + ---------- + ------------- + ------ + ----------- +
```

**Select Ratio**

We're basically doing the same thing here, but it may be easy to get lost in the casting and divide-by-zero checking. So hopefully I've split it into enough lines that it makes it clear

```
select    u.account_id
        , r.request_id
        , r.creation_date
        , r.amount
        , (...) as SumOfFailed -- same as above
        , cast(( -- convert integer to float
            select COUNT(*)
                from #request
                where account_id = u.account_id
                    and request_type = 'positiv'
            ) as float)
            / nullif( -- if divisor is zero, return null
            CAST((
                select COUNT(*)
                    from #request
                    where account_id = u.account_id
                        and request_type = 'negativ'
            ) as float), 0) as Ratio
    from ... -- same as above
```

which gives us

```
+ ---------- + ---------- + ------------- + ------ + ----------- + ----- +
| account_id | request_id | creation_date | amount | SumOfFailed | Ratio |
+ ---------- + ---------- + ------------- + ------ + ----------- + ----- +
| 2          | 5          | 2016-03-12    | 110.12 | 38.42       | 2     |
| 5          | 10         | 2016-10-18    | 13.02  | 0           | Null  |
+ ---------- + ---------- + ------------- + ------ + ----------- + ----- +
```

**Code block**

So all together, your sql statement will be something like this, with some minor differences to make it work in postgre.

```
select u.account_id
        , request_id
        , r.creation_date
        , r.amount
        , ( select isnull(SUM(amount),0) -- replaces a null value with 0
                from #request
                    where account_id = u.account_id
                        and request_type = 'negativ' ) as SumOfFailed
        , cast((
            select COUNT(*)
                from #request
                where account_id = u.account_id
                    and request_type = 'positiv'
            ) as float)
            / nullif(
            CAST((
                select COUNT(*)
                    from #request
                        where account_id = u.account_id
                            and request_type = 'negativ'
            ) as float),0) as Ratio
    from #user_account u
    inner join #request r on r.account_id = u.account_id
    where u.account_type = 'A'
        and r.request_id = (
            select top 1 request_id
                from #request r_sq
                where r_sq.account_id = u.account_id
                    and r_sq.request_type = 'positiv'
                order by creation_date desc
        )
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: the amount of willingness to help here is INSANE. thank you very much, everything works as you described. I just used "limit 1" instead of "top 1 " and "coalesce" instead of "isnull" for postgresql. Awesome walkthrough, 11/10 would ask again.